# Pass shiny widget initial values from server

Tags: r, shiny

To enable sharing of a particular state of an app I want to set widget initial `selected` values based on the URL hash provided.  I just don't know how to pass  the hash value at the initialisation stage.  This illustrates:

```
library(shiny); library(shinyjs)

urlCode = "shinyjs.pageURL = function(params){ if(params[0] != ''){location.href = location.origin + '/#' + params[0];}}"

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(session$clientData$url_hash, {
    hash = substr(session$clientData$url_hash, 2,10)
    # I need to pass hash to selectInput selected value
    # and pass `toupper(hash)` to tabsetPanel selected value
  })

  observeEvent(input$txt, {
    js$pageURL(input$txt) # appends tab choice to URL as hash
  })
}

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = urlCode),
  selectInput("txt", "tab choice:", c("one", "two", "three"), selected = 'two'), # to be initialised as hash value

  # tab menu
  tabsetPanel(id = 'tab_menu', selected = 'TWO',  # to be initialised as hash value
              tabPanel("ONE",   textInput('txt_one', 'one text', '')),
              tabPanel("TWO",   textInput('txt_two', 'two text', '')),
              tabPanel("THREE", textInput('txt_three', 'three text', ''))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=T))
```

[image]

Values currently initialise as 'two' (selectInput) and 'TWO' (tabsetPanel), but these need to take their initial values from the `hash` parameter in the case that the URL call is e.g. `http://domain/#three` (as opposed to root `http://domain/`).  Grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `"#"` and use `update*` functions like this :

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    hash <- gsub(pattern = "#", replacement = "", x = session$clientData$url_hash)
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "tab_menu", selected = toupper(hash))
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "txt", selected = hash)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("txt", "tab choice:", c("one", "two", "three"), selected = 'two'), # to be initialised as hash value

  # tab menu
  tabsetPanel(
    id = 'tab_menu', selected = 'TWO',  # to be initialised as hash value
    tabPanel("ONE",   textInput('txt_one', 'one text', '')),
    tabPanel("TWO",   textInput('txt_two', 'two text', '')),
    tabPanel("THREE", textInput('txt_three', 'three text', ''))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This looks great. I've just aware that this binds the widget choice to the URL permanently rather than just at the initialisation stage.  Is there any way to constrain it to initialisation?  I wonder if I'll encounter problems with `observe` triggers if the system is receiving 2 instructions to open a tab - by user clicking on it and then the updated URL tripping a duplicate instruction..?

Comment: Here's my updated working code: https://gist.github.com/geotheory/38c64a770ca65a873b07f046088cb0c8

Comment: Yes you're right, the observer will be executed several times (the instructions will be the same since you update the url when a tab is clicked, so not really a problem). You can use `observeEvent` with `once = TRUE`, the observer will be run only once, at the initialisation stage. I've commented your gist.

Comment: Thanks very much Victor :)